# Can the mirror formula be applied if object is not placed on the principal axis of the mirror?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I have seen the derivation of this formula, and it was derived under the case that the object was placed on the principal axis of the mirror. If somebody knows, can they please share the formula to calculate the position of the image if the object is not placed on the principal axis.

Comment: Which mirror formula and what kind of mirror do you mean?

Comment: Spherical mirror(both concave and convex)

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal mirror there is no effect but in practice, if you move off the optical axis, you experience effects such as

- apodisation or vignetting

  the intensity decreases towards the edge of the field
- distortion

  shift and magnification variation as function of field position
- aberration

  astigmatism: different focus for horizontal and vertical features

  coma

  higher order focus effects